# Why are there different results when using regular expressions when executing commands in the cmd terminal and when executing cmd commands in golang?

Tags: windows, go, cmd

**Two different results of executing the command in the cmd terminal and executing the cmd command in golang**

### cmd

```
C:\Users\Administrator>cmd /c tasklist | findstr /R /I "\<cmd.exe\>"
cmd.exe                       4852 Console                    1      5,676 K
cmd.exe                      11736 Console                    1      4,836 K
```

### golang

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "tasklist", "|", "findstr", "/R", "/I", "cmd.exe")
    output, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))

    // Use regular filtering
    cmd2 := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "tasklist", "|", "findstr", "/R", "/I", "\\<cmd.exe\\>")
    output, err = cmd2.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}

result：
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___go_build_demo_go.exe
cmd.exe                       4852 Console                    1      5,380 K
cmd.exe                      11816 Console                    1      5,044 K

panic: exit status 1
```

Comment: The second `cmd.exe` is the one you just generated with your command, so the PID is random. The memory size isn't a constant either and is ok to fall and rise for most processes. So your outputs are quite what I'd expect.

Comment: Two side suggestions: 1. print the command output *before* panicking (you don't have a chance to see the output at all), 2. use `.CombinedOutput()` - or any way that allows you to also see what's printed on stderr

Comment: ```findstr /R /I "\<cmd.exe\>"``` does not do what you think it does! `.` has a specific regex function, so perhaps you should escape that function, ```findstr.exe /R /I "\<cmd\.exe\>"```.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you for your kind reply. Finally, I solved it in this way:**

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "tasklist", "|", "findstr", "/R", "/I", "cmd.exe")
output, _ := cmd.Output()
fmt.Println(string(output))
//***************************************************************************//
cmd1 := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "tasklist")
cmd2 := exec.Command("findstr", "/R", "/I", "\\<cmd.exe\\>")
cmd2.Stdin, _ = cmd1.StdoutPipe()
cmd1.Start()
data, _ := cmd2.Output()
cmd1.Wait()
fmt.Println(string(data))

result:

Result of regular expression not used
cmd.exe                       5188 Console                    1      6,184 K
cmdcmd.exe                    1260 Console                    1      4,980 K

Results of using regular expressions
cmd.exe                       5188 Console                    1      6,184 K
```

**Although the second way is a little more troublesome, it is really useful. I wonder if there is a better way?**

Comment: @stephan@LeGEC@Compo